# Wrong localisation in Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

When executed in firebase cloud functions, the following command returns the American format instead of the localised one.
However, it works well in browsers.

```
price.toLocaleString("pt-BR", {
  maximumFractionDigits: 2
});
```

Is there any way toLocaleString() works properly in firebase cloud functions ?

**Update:**

```
let price = 1456.21
let formattedPrice = price.toLocaleString("pt-BR", {maximumFractionDigits: 2});

//Value of formattedPrice expected: 1.456,21 (it works in browsers).
//Value of formattedPrice returned in Firebase Cloud Functions: 1,456.21
```

Maybe it something related to the default ICU of Node (--with-intl=small-icu) . To support internationalization, it seems the value should be --with-intl=full-icu .

https://nodejs.org/api/intl.html#intl_options_for_building_node_js

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What is "proper" and "wrong" here? In other words: what is the output you get from running this code? What is the output that expected from the code? Also note: we have no way of knowing what the value of `price` is and how is affects the output. So it would be easier to help if you hardcode that value, instead of showing an uninitialized variable.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen For example, if the value of price is 1739.23 and this command runs in browser, it returns "1.739,23", that is European format, but in cloud functions, it returns "1,739.23", that is American format.

Comment: the accepted anser probably need to change as intl is no longer supported

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't depend on special flags for building the version of node used in Cloud Functions.  What you can do instead is pull in a module that deals with formatting locale strings.  For example, you can use the [intl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/intl) module:

```
npm install intl
```

The use this:

```
const intl = require('intl')
const format = intl.NumberFormat("pt-BR", {maximumFractionDigits: 2})
console.log(format.format(price))
```

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more please? I have `NumberFormat` without this package as well, and importing this package does not seem to take effect on autocomplete and I cannot see method details as well.

Comment: ⚠️ intl seems no longer active/supported (last version is 5yo...).

Answer (score 8):

⚠️ *intl* seems no longer active/supported (last version is 4yo...).

I've achieved adding the real intl as follow:

1. Add `full-icu` dependencies on your Firebase Cloud Functions:
   `npm install full-icu --save`
2. **Edit** you functions (after a successful deployment) on [console.cloud.google.com](https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/list) (don't forget to select the right google dev project)
3. Add `NODE_ICU_DATA` env var with value `node_modules/full-icu`
4. Save and wait 1 or 2 min for the functions to be deploy.

Furter update will not remove this env, and I was able to use Intl apis from Luxon successfully.

Comment: Thanks for the information! It sound promising and unfortunately it is not working for me: "node: could not initialize ICU (check NODE_ICU_DATA or --icu-data-dir parameters)". It seems full-icu does not get installed correctly. Did you faced a smiliar problem?

Comment: no, maybe you can chat with me on twitter or something if you want help troubleshoot that.

Comment: Problem is solved. I put "full-icu" accidently to the "devDependencies"... I moved it to "dependencies" and it works like a charm now! Thanks for this great solution @Hugo Gresse

Comment: This has been working great until recently, but now it's not working, I'm getting dates in US format again. The only thing I've changed is switching to typescript, but I don't think that can have an effect?

Comment: when did you notice that? I'm using this for https://github.com/HugoGresse/Ical2Api/ which is really needed and had no issue (last deploy is 26d ago)