# toLocaleString not working on firebase cloudFunctions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

My node 8 function, hosted at Firebase Cloud Functions isn't working as expected. I've a `toLocaleString` call passing all parameters to format in Brazilian currency format, but I getting the default `EN` format.

The function:

```
const value = 10825.20645
const formatted = value.toLocaleString('pt-br', { 
    style: 'currency', 
    currency: 'BRL', 
    decimals: 2 
})
```

**Expected result**

- `R$ 10.825,21`

**Actual result at CloudFunction**

- `R$ 10,825.21`

Running the same function on browser is working fine

```js
const value = 10825.20645
const formatted = value.toLocaleString('pt-br', { 
    style: 'currency', 
    currency: 'BRL', 
    decimals: 2 
})
  
console.log(formatted) // R$ 10.825,21
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49012433/wrong-localisation-in-firebase-cloud-function

That may help.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this and post here the status!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this (in part, I'll explain), I used [INTL API](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl) as suggested by @hybrdthry911. By default, nodejs only load the EN lang.

```
const intl = require('intl')
const locale = intl.NumberFormat('pt-br', { 
    style: 'currency', 
    currency: 'BRL', 
    decimals: 2 
})
const value = 10825.20645
const formatted = locale.format(value)
console.log(formatted) // R$10.825,21
```

But, it still different from my expected result. In browsers, I get an space after the currency symbol, but with INTL.

- Expected: `R$ 10.825,21`
- Result: `R$10.825,21`

It's a small problem, I'll do a search about.